# Regex matching in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, regex, grep

Here is a snippet from my shell script -

```
regex="<version>([0-9]*)\.([0-9]*)\.([0-9]*)([^<]*)<\/version>.*"

#some unrelated lines of code

    echo $(grep -m 1 "<version>" $1)
    if [[ $(grep -m 1 "<version>" $1) =~ $regex ]]
    then
        main_version = "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        feature_version = "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        patch_version = "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
        tag = "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    else
        echo "$1: Version not Found" >&2
    fi
```

But it is showing me the following output -

```
<version>1.1.7-release</version> <!-- ABC version -->
abc/xyz/pom.xml: Version not Found
```

But according to my understanding, `regex` should match with the output of `grep`(i echoed it to terminal for better clarity). So can someone tell what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I tried this on a file containing your stuff, and it matches... what is your bash release ? (bash --version)

Comment: Also, what *exactly* is the output from `grep`? `echo $(grep ...)` will mangle the output in a number of ways (in fact, `echo $(somecommand)` is almost always a bad idea). Try `grep ... | LC_ALL=C cat -vet` -- the `cat` command will convert a variety of normally-invisible characters to visible forms, and add a "$" to the end of each line so you can see where they are.

Comment: I found the error, it was caused by `export -f custom_function` to use the custom_function in `xargs` and ofcourse the aboce snippet was part of custom_funcion. thanks for giving your time